# ExpandableListView OnClick go to the activity does not work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick, switch-statement

I have got ExpandableListView. It looks like this http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android-expandable-listview.jpg . I just want to OnChildClick for example Despicable Me 2 go to the SecondActivity and send PutExtra string with "Despicable Me 2". I know how to use PutExtra and GetExtra method.

Can someone give me advice how to solve this problem? I tried to go with switches but it does not work it does not do anything(It just stay in ExpandableListView).

Here is MainActivity.java:

```
Public string movie;

expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        switch(groupPosition)
        {
        //Top250

        case 0: switch(childPosition)
        {
        case 0: movie="The Conjuring";
        intent0.putExtra("text1", movie);
        startActivity(intent0);
        break;
        case 1: movie="Despicable Me 2";
        intent0.putExtra("text1", movie);
        startActivity(intent0);
        break;
        }
        break;
        //Now Showing
        case 1: switch(childPosition)
        {
        case 0: 
            break;
        }
        break;
        //Coming Soon
        case 2:switch(childPosition)
        {
        case 0: 
            break;
        }

        break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I downloaded this code from http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ you can see all of xml and activities here except SecondActivity.

Comment: Did you try click on first group first/second element, because it doesnt look like you implemented anything for "Now Showing". It should work for **"Top 250"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the intent inside the switch case
like this

```
 case 0: switch(childPosition)
                    {
                    case 0: Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    movie="The Conjuring";
                    intent0.putExtra("text1", movie);
            startActivity(intent0);
                        break;
```

or

```
if(childPosition ==1)
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    movie="The Conjuring";
                    intent0.putExtra("text1", movie);
                     startActivity(intent0);
```